# Python dictionary to json.dumps flask not working can't send response

Tags: json, python-2.7, dictionary, post, flask

I'm building the back end for an tensorflow app and basically after I do my classification I want to return the results to the client in JSON format.

So after my classification I get two values a `"name"` and `"%"`

## imports

```
import json
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response #import objects from the Flask model
app = Flask(__name__) #define app using Flask
```

## function called by api call

Basically this returns this dictionary in the variable Items

`{'moulin de la galette renoir': 0.0080302889, 'les demoiselles d avignon picassso': 0.7823543, 'starry night over the rhone van gogh': 0.01457829, 'wheatfields with crows van gogh': 0.049212866, 'guernica picassso': 0.14582427}`

```
 classify()
     do some code here ...

     # Sort to show labels of first prediction in order of confidence
     top_k = predictions[0].argsort()[-len(predictions[0]):][::-1]

     #items within object
            items = {}
            for node_id in top_k:
                human_string = label_lines[node_id]
                score = predictions[0][node_id]
                #stores human string and score in item
                items[human_string] = score
     return items
```

## api

```
@app.route('/inception', methods=['POST'])
def inception():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({'message' : 'failed'})
    file = request.files['file']
    output = classify(file)
    #print just to see the format of the output
    print(output)
    return Response(json.dumps(output),  mimetype='application/json')
```

This should post back items in json form but it doesn't.

If from classify() I hard code the exact same value as output equal it works.

so:

```
return {'moulin de la galette renoir': 0.0080302889, 'les demoiselles d avignon picassso': 0.7823543, 'starry night over the rhone van gogh': 0.01457829, 'wheatfields with crows van gogh': 0.049212866, 'guernica picassso': 0.14582427}
```

Comment: When you say "This should post back items in json form but it doesn't." - what happens instead?

Comment: See Matt's question. This seems like it should work. Alternatively, you can use flask's `jsonify`, which you already included, to return the result. Doing it this way should also set the header.

Comment: @MattHealy I get thrown a 500 error in postman when I do the post request.

Comment: @jwang Jsonify can't convert a dictionary, you only get sent back a single group of numbers or it either throws a 500 error as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figure it out, basically in tensorflow code which I didn't include my value for score was a numpy float 32 type. Json dumps can't convert this and that's why it wasn't working.

`score = float(predictions[0][node_id])`

This minor change in the code fixes the issue. A lesson learned in always making sure you know your data types. Thanks for your help guys ^^